# Reset orders,invoices and shipping to 000001

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can i reset orders,invoices and shipping to 000001 in magento Comunnity 1.7.0.2 ?

What is the simplest and safest method ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a table in the database which stored increment id of order. 
It is called “eav_entity_store” table. 
You can check which entity type id belongs to which entity by looking at eav_entity_type table. 
You can run following query to update last increment id for the order.

```
update eav_entity_store
inner join eav_entity_type on eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
set eav_entity_store.increment_last_id=000001
where eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```